# How can I change the arrow on a <select> tag?

Tags: html, svg, shopify, liquid

I would like to change the standard arrow on a  button with options to an svg icon. The first image is how it looks now and the second is how I would like it to look. I would like to style the actual icon on the button and not the style of the options that will appear under it once clicked.

[image: Image of how it appears now]
[image: Image of how I would like it to appear]

HTML/Liquid:

```
<select name="id" id="ProductSelect" class="product-single__variants">
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.available %}
       <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</option>
    {% else %}
       <option disabled="disabled">
         {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
       </option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

SVG File:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 64.57"><title>Asset 2</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path d="M4,36.28H66.34L44.89,57.74a4,4,0,1,0,5.66,5.66L78.83,35.11h0a4,4,0,0,0,.5-.61c.07-.1.11-.21.17-.31a3.85,3.85,0,0,0,.2-.37,3.65,3.65,0,0,0,.13-.41c0-.11.08-.22.1-.33a4,4,0,0,0,.08-.79h0a4,4,0,0,0-.08-.77c0-.12-.07-.23-.1-.35a3.58,3.58,0,0,0-.12-.4,4,4,0,0,0-.21-.4c-.05-.1-.1-.2-.16-.29a3.88,3.88,0,0,0-.5-.61L50.54,1.17a4,4,0,1,0-5.66,5.66L66.34,28.28H4a4,4,0,0,0,0,8Z"/></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: You will need to use a custom dropdown library, since HTML <select> is not quite customizable at this point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the option of a html "select"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select) The question is about the  `<option>` but it applies to the whole `<select>` as the accepted answer explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an svg as a css background image like so:

```
.product-single__variants { 
 background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,{{ icon.svg | asset_url | replace: '"', "'" }}")  no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to the same thing before. Here's what worked for me.

```
select-dropdown {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
    background: url('path/to/file.jpg') no-repeat right center !important; 
    background-color: white !important;
}
```